# Get matches between two delimiters when potentially nested

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

The specific delimiters for my case are opening and closing parenthesis.  When not nested, I can get the text between them as follows:

```
$input = 'sometext(moretext)andmoretext(somemoretext)andevenmoretext(andmore)';
preg_match_all('#\((.*?)\)#', $input, $match);
echo('<pre>'.print_r($match[1],1).'</pre>');

Array
(
    [0] => moretext
    [1] => somemoretext
    [2] => andmore
)
```

However, when I have nested characters, I run into some snags, and get the following.

```
$input = 'sometext(moretext)andmoretext(somemore(with(bitof(littletext)text)more(andmore)text)text)andevenmoretext(andmore)';
preg_match_all('#\((.*?)\)#', $input, $match);
echo('<pre>'.print_r($match[1],1).'</pre>');

Array
(
    [0] => moretext
    [1] => somemore(with(bitof(littletext
    [2] => andmore
    [3] => andmore
)
```

How can I return the entire string between the delimiters:

```
Array
(
    [0] => moretext
    [1] => somemore(with(bitof(littletext)text)more(andmore)text)text
    [2] => andmore
)
```

PS.  Ultimately, I will be using recursive PHP to perform the same task on any top-level matches that also contain parenthesis.

Comment: With a recursive call: `\(([^()]*+(?:(?R)[^()]*]*+)\)` where `(?R)` refers to the whole pattern itself.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte  I've never heard of a recursive call.  What are your referring to as "the whole pattern"?

Comment: `(?R)` is a placeholder for the regex itself. oops, a typo: `\(([^()]*+(?:(?R)[^()]*)*+)\)`

Comment: You can use `\w+(?:\((?:[^()]*|(?R))*\))?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this [recursive regex pattern](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php) to match matching `(...)`:

```
preg_match_all('/\( ( (?: [^()]* | (?R) )* ) \)/x', $input, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BCmQb4/1)

`(?R)` recurses the entire pattern.

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => moretext
    [1] => somemore(with(bitof(littletext)text)more(andmore)text)text
    [2] => andmore
)
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava,  I finally became okay with simple expressions, but this one is a doozy!  Works as described, however.  I will read up on the manual section you listed.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of doing it, here is a non-regex solution.

```
function delimeterSplit( $input )
{
    $str = '';
    $output = array();

    $op = 0;
    $cp = 0;

    foreach( str_split( $input ) as $k => $v )
    {
        if( $v === '(' )
        {
            ++$op;
        }
        if( $input[ $k ] === ')' )
        {
            ++$cp;
        }
        if( ( ( $op === 1 && $v !== '(' ) || $op > 1 ) && $op !== $cp )
        {
            $str .= $v;
        }
        if( $op > 0 && $op === $cp )
        {
            $op = 0;
            $cp = 0;
            $output[] = $str;
            $str = '';
        }
    }

    return $output;
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r( delimeterSplit( 'sometext(moretext)andmoretext(somemoretext)andevenmoretext(andmore)' ), true ).'</pre>';

echo '<pre>'.print_r( delimeterSplit( 'sometext(moretext)andmoretext(somemore(with(bitof(littletext)text)more(andmore)text)text)andevenmoretext(andmore)' ), true ).'</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => moretext
    [1] => somemoretext
    [2] => andmore
)

Array
(
    [0] => moretext
    [1] => somemore(with(bitof(littletext)text)more(andmore)text)text
    [2] => andmore
)
```